# Accessing private members from other classes

Tags: c#, private

In Java, if two classes are defined inside one top-level class, they have access to each other's private members (fields, constructors, methods). So in a situation like the following you could use all of the private members of `ClassA` inside `ClassB`, and vice-versa.

```
public class TopLevelClass {

     private static class ClassA {
         // Code omitted
     }

     private static class ClassB {
         // Code omitted
     }
 }
```

Can you do anything similar in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with nested classes in C#, two separate (not nested within each other) classes cannot access each other's private members (even though they share a parent). They *can* however access private members of the parent class.

You can get access to private members using reflection if you really need to, though of course, if you need access to them they probably shouldn't be `private` in the first place.

See [Nested Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that was the answer - I just wanted confirmation. One approach I find really useful in Java is to write helper classes that are only of use to the top-level class they're defined in. For these classes I can just make everything private and don't need to worry about writing accessor methods.

Comment: @pbabcdefp There are always auto-properties :)